# Write a function in zshrc that can take a parameter and can handle flags

Tags: google-chrome, zsh

I usually need a chrome page opened to localhost:3000 when I am developing. So, I just run the following cmd:
`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app=http://localhost:3000`

Since I use this frequently and sometimes my port changes. I want to write a function in zsh where `ch` will open chrome in `localhost:3000` while `ch 2500` will open chrome in `localhost:2500`.

So far, this is what I have managed to do:

```
ch () {
    command "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
}
```

This opens a new chrome window but displays an error/warning in the console: `/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGVA/AppleGVA-9.1.12/Sources/Slices/Driver/AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 3`

But when I add a flag:

```
ch () {
    command "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --app=http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Nothing happens and I end up getting an error:
`ch:1: no such file or directory: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --app=http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it does not work with the added flag is that you added the flag within the double quotes, essentially telling `zsh` that it is part of the command name. The only reason any quotes are needed is that the path to and name of `Google Chrome` contain whitespaces. Whitespaces are used by `zsh` (and any other Unix shell) as separator between *words*. Quoting a string tells `zsh` that it should be interpreted as a single word, no matter how many whitespaces (or other syntactic elements) are in it.

One way to do this correctly is:

```
ch () {
    "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --app=http://localhost:${1:-3000}
}
```

- Here only the path to `Google Chrome` is quoted, while the flag is separate.
- The keyword `command` is not necessary. It would only tell `zsh` to use an external command instead of a function or alias of the same name, which is most likely not a risk here (The alias or function would have to be named `"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"`)
- `${1:-3000}` is substituted with the first parameter (`$1`) passed to `ch`. If it is undefined or has a null-value (e.g. `""`) "3000" will be substituted instead. So running

  ```
  ch 2500
  ```

  will open Chrome on `http://localhost:2500`, but running

  ```
  ch
  ```

  will open Chrome on `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I am still getting the error in the command prompt:
`/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGVA/AppleGVA-9.1.12/Sources/Slices/Driver/AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 3`

Comment: I am not really sure about that. But if everything else works just fine, I would assume that it is more of a debug message an can be ignored. Chances are that Chrome is issuing this message even when it is started from the GUI, you just can not see it then.